# Double integral as product of two integrals - geometric interpretation?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

In the context of double integrals, I was wondering -

> Assume we write $\int \int _D f(x)g(y)dxdy =\int_a^b f(x) dx \cdot  \int _c^d g(y)dy  $ (where $D$ is the rectangle $[a,b]\times[c,d]$). The double integral on the LHS represents the volume bounded between $z=f(x)g(y)$ and the $xy$ plane, above $D$ ($f,g>0$ for example). In this case, is there any geometric interpretation we can give to each of the integrals $\int_a^b f(x) dx , \,  \int _c^d g(y)dy  $ ?

Each of these integrals calculates the area bounded between a one-variable function and the corresponding axis. But is there any way to relate these areas (or integrals) to the three dimensional volume bounded between $z=f(x)g(y)$ and the $xy$ plane, above $D$?

Thanks

Comment: Sure, the product of the areas gives the volume.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I obviously understand that, but was looking for a geometric perspective. i.e., can I visualize these two areas somehow and relate them to the volume?

Comment: Not really, and a simple dimensional analysis would show that. The notion of a "volume" assumes $x$, $y$, and $z$ all have dimensions of length. But the notion of an "area" assumes $f$ and $g$ also have dimensions of length, which is a contradiction of interpretation if $z=fg$. What you're seeing here is that the interpretation of a function as an embedded graph is "not natural".

Comment: Write $h(x,y)=f(x)g(y)$. Note that $h$ is a special type of function - it is separable - most functions of two variables are not separable. The volume you are evaluating in $\int_D h \, dx \, dy$ is therefore a special shape. Each slice parallel to the x-z plane is similar, it's just scaled (by $g(y)$). The volume of such a shape is the product of $\int f(x) \, dx$ and the 'average' scaling factor - which is $\int g(y) \, dy$.

Comment: @Blitzer I think your comment is worth turning into an answer, and it could help get this off of the unanswered list

Comment: OK - I'll do that

Comment: @NinadMunshi: Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $h(x,y)=f(x)g(y)$.
Note that $h$ is a special type of function - it is separable - most functions of two variables are not separable.
The volume you are evaluating in $\int_D h \, dx \, dy$ is therefore a special shape. Each slice parallel to the x-z plane is similar, it's just scaled (by $g(y)$).
The volume of such a shape is the product of $\int f(x) \, dx$ and the 'average' scaling factor - which is  $\int g(y) \, dy$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the interpretation @Blitzer! That's exactly the kind of perspective I was looking for